# Laravel email verify after change in profile (Breeze)

Tags: laravel, laravel-breeze

Email verification (*Laravel 10 + Breeze*) works fine for registration but it doesn't seem suitable for changing email in the profile :

- the displayed message and email are same as registration
- if a syntax error in new email we only have buttons "resend" and "logout"

[image]

Have I missed something or do you know example to customize the email edition in profile page ?

Thanks & cheers